# Executing a command in View-Model when View is idle using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I want to execute a command in my view-model when my view is idle **and I don't want code behind the view.**

Is That possible ? (If the answer is using the `EventToCommand` feature from MVVM Light much better)
How ?

**NOTE:** that I already know that I can use the event `ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle`, but the question is about how to get a clean .xaml file without code behind it, not even a simple:

```
ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += (...) dataContext (...)
```

Thanks again.

Comment: Any specific reason to avoid code behind? There's nothing wrong with some view-related code, if it's much cleaner and shorter than XAML version.

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewModel constructor do the same thing as you were trying to do in code behind. Something like:

```
 public ViewModel()
    {
        ComponentDispatcher.ThreadIdle += ComponentDispatcher_ThreadIdle;
    }

    private void ComponentDispatcher_ThreadIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Idle");
    }
```